# Mistake in proof about vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation

Hello this is my first post on here and I have a question about an error in a proof. My Linear Algebra professor was covering Linear Independence, Basis, and Dimension for Vector Spaces. We got to a proof from the textbook and he said the proof is wrong. He said to try and figure out what is wrong with it. I have been trying to figure out what is wrong and after thinking about it, talking with peers, and with my professor I have narrowed it down to a single sentence within the proof. I think that it is a wrong word choice. He said it is very subtle. I was hoping some of you can provide some insight.

THM 6.11: Let $W$ be a subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$. Then: 
(a) $W$ is finite-dimensional and $\dim W \le \dim V$. 
(b) $\dim W = \dim V$ if and only if $W = V$.

He has a problem with the proof of part (a) which is as follows.

Proof (a) Let $\dim V = n$. If $W = \{\mathbf{0}\}$, then $\dim(W) = 0 \le n = \dim V$. If $W$ is nonzero, then any basis $\mathcal{B}$ for $V$ (containing $n$ vectors) certainly spans $W$, since $W$ is contained in $V$. But $\mathcal{B}$  can be reduced to a basis $\mathcal{B'}$ for $W$ (containing at most $n$ vectors), by Theorem 6.10(f). Hence, $W$ is finite-dimensional and $\dim W \le n = \dim V$. 

Theorem 6.10(f) states: Let $V$ be a vector space with $\dim V = n$. Then: (f) Any spanning set for $V$ can be reduced to a basis for $V$. 

My professor said that me and my peers were right about the error being in the sentence, "But $\mathcal{B}$  can be reduced to a basis $\mathcal{B'}$ for $W$ (containing at most $n$ vectors), by Theorem 6.10(f)." I believe that the error has something to do with with the word **reduced**. I asked him and he said that I was on the right track but he didn't give me a clear answer. What is wrong with this proof? More specifically the sentence above? Any help would be much appreciated. (Textbook: Linear Algebra: A Modern Introduction by David Poole 4th edition. The proof is found in section 6.2: page 456)

Comment: Suggestion: it would be worth while improving your use of MathJax.  I was going to edit your post but found there are lots of things which are not done well.  For example instead of `*W*$=$*V*` it is much better to write `$W=V$`.

Comment: I apologize this was my first time using Mathjax. I'll try to work on improving it! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: "But B can be reduced to a basis B′ for W (**containting** at most n vectors" I take it your professor isn't talking about this error?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The error is the following. Theorem 6.10(f) says that if you have a set that spans $V$, you can remove elements ("reduce") until you get a basis. In the proof of 6.11, the elements in the basis of $V$ may not belong to $W$, so the argument does not apply.

For example, maybe $V=\mathbb R^3$, and you take the canonical basis $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$. Then if $W=\{(x,y,z): x=y=z\}$, none of the three elements in the basis belongs to $W$.

The usual argument is that a basis of $W$ will be linearly independent, and so it will also be linearly independent in $V$, and it follows that $\dim W\leq \dim V$.

Comment: Yep, when you say it that way it is clear.  +1

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

Your professor is correct.

The problem is with the word " reduced"

Let us look at an example.

Let W be the subspace of $\mathbb {R}^2$  spanned by $\{(1,1)\}.$

Let $ B=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ be a basis for  $\mathbb {R}^2$

Then $B$ spans $W$, but we can not reduce $B$ to a basis for $W$

Comment: Thank you for giving me some more insight!

Comment: Thanks for your attention and understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is a difference in use of terminology here but I would say that the problem is with the statement "$B$ spans $W$".

The way I have always seen the term used is as follows.

- We define ${\rm span}(B)=\{\hbox{linear combinations of vectors in $B$}\}$.
- Then "$B$ spans $W$" means that ${\rm span}(B)$ equals $W$.

In the proof you have quoted, they appear to be saying that "$B$ spans $W$" means that ${\rm span}(B)$ **contains** $W$.

So it is a question of using the precise meaning of terminology.  BTW, I would not agree with your professor that it is a "very subtle" error, IMHO it is a blatant error :)

Comment: It isn't a terminology issue. Even if we take the weird interpretation that "$B$ spans $W$" means "the linear span of $B$ contains $W$", there is still no reason why $B$ can be reduced to a basis of $W$. The author is simply wrong.

Comment: My professor didn't have a problem with that part of the proof.  It was the sentence afterward that he had a problem with. Thank you for your help!